# Excel & Silverlight 4

Tags: excel, silverlight-4.0

I have created a Silverlight 4 app out-of-browser with elevated trust.

The app creates .xls files using AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

My application requires an Excel installed on local machine.

The problem is, users don't want to install Excel on every computer that will use the app.

They only have one workstation that has Excel installed.

Is there a way to create the Excel differently that would not require to have Excel on the PC ?

Is it even possible to automate COM resources from another machine ?

Comment: You need only export a plain sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can not do this using COM.